# dispatch the same event order of arrival in saga and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

**case 1**

say I `dispatch({type: TEST_EVENT})` in UI with `useEffect`, and both my saga and reducer are listening to the same event. Who will get it first.

**case 2**

say I `dispatch({type: TEST_EVENT})` in UI with `useEffect`, then saga listening to it, then in saga I do `yield put({type: 'TEST_EVENT_1'}`, then reducer (if listening `TEST_EVENT_1`) will be able to receive it. Could someone confirm this?

Comment: Yup, the action always goes to reducer first, then is handled in sagas. The second case is the correct way to do something in saga before the data gets to reducer.

Answer (score 1):

case 1: From the `redux-saga` middleware [source code](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/4348497e1c22bb5656c1905af19e25f8e7d29c61/packages/core/src/internal/middleware.js#L27-L28), we know if both saga and reducer are listening to the same action type. The reducer will get the action firstly.

case 2: The recommended workflow is: dispatch `SOME_EVENT` action => watcher saga => worker saga => do something(call API, computation, etc..) => dispatch `SOME_EVENT_FULFILLED`/`SOME_EVENT_REJECTED` action to reducer.